# Solving congruences with cubics

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, hensels-lemma

I want to be able to solve $$x^3 +6x^2+x+5 \equiv 0\mod{13^2} $$

I have used Hensel's Lemma, and currently have: $ f(1+13t_1) \equiv 0\mod{13^2} $ is equivalent to $ 16t_1+117t_1^2+169t_1^3 \equiv -1\mod{13}$ but I don't know where to take it from here?

Comment: Reducing $\!\bmod 13\,$ the 2nd polynomial  in $\,t_1\,$ yields $\!\bmod 13\!:\ 3t_1 \equiv -1\equiv 12\iff {t_1\equiv 4}\iff \color{#c00}{t_1 = 4+13j},\,$ therefore $\,x = 1+13\color{#c00}{t_1} = 1+13(\color{#c00}{4+13k})\equiv 53\pmod{\!13^2}\ \ $

Comment: Are you trying to find *all* the solutions mod $13^2$, or just the one that corresponds to the solution $x\equiv1$ mod $13$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find *all* solutions to an equation mod $p^2$, you need to start by finding all solutions mod $p$ and then "lift" them to solutions mod $p^2$.  For the cubic $x^3+6x^2+x+5$ we have

$$x^3+6x^2+x+5\equiv(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)\mod13$$

so the solutions mod $13$ are $1$, $2$, and $4$.

To "lift" the solution $x\equiv1$ mod $13$, we write $x=1+13u$ and note that

$$x^n=(1+13u)^n\equiv1+13nu\mod13^2$$

(In particular, it's not necessary to compute any of the coefficients of higher-order powers of $u$.) In this way, we get

$$x^3+6x^2+x+5\equiv(1+39u)+6(1+26u)+(1+13u)+5\equiv13+208u=13(1+16u)\mod13^2$$

This is satisfied if $1+16u\equiv0$ mod $13$, which simplifies to $1+3u\equiv0$ mod $13$, from which it's easy to see that $u=4$ does the trick, giving us $x=1+13\cdot4=53$ as one of the solutions mod $13^2$.

I'll leave the lifting of $x\equiv2$ and $4$ mod $13$ as an exercise (unless the OP requests more details), noting only that when writing $x=r+pu$ (for a general root $r$ and prime modulus $p$), we have

$$x^n=(r+pu)^n\equiv r^n+pnr^{n-1}u\mod p^2$$

Remark: I've written $u$ here instead of $t_1$, but one is certainly free to use a notation $x=r+13t_r$. Also, it looks to me like the answer by sirious jumped from a (correct) derivation of $t_1=4$ for the lifting of the root $x=1$ mod $13$ to a (coincidentally correct) conclusion that $x=4$ is a solution mod $13^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We can see that for $x=4$ we have:

$f(4)=169\equiv 0\bmod 13^2$

So general form of solution can be:

$x\equiv 4\bmod 13^2$

Now you found:

$16t_1+117t_1^2+169t_1^3\equiv -1 \bmod 13$

$16\equiv 3 \bmod 13$

$117\equiv 0\bmod 13$

$169\equiv \bmod 13$

$16t_1\equiv 3t_1\equiv-1\bmod 13$

$\Rightarrow t_1=4$

which is primitive root and general form of solution is $x\equiv 4\bmod 13^2$

Update:

By direct division we have:

$f(x)=x^3+6x^2+x+5=(x-4)(x^2+10x+41)+169=169 k$

Let $x^2+10x+41 =g(x)$, we can see that for $x-4\approx 3.4\rightarrow x\approx 7.4$ we have:

$g(7.4)\approx 169$

which gives $k=4.4$ that is we have:

$f(7.4)\approx 4.4\times 169$

By direct division of $g(x)$ by ($x-7.4$) we obtain:

$g(x)=(x-7.4)(x+17.4)+169=169 m$

etc.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Found it really useful, sorry to pick your brains further but with the squared on the 13 how do you go about solving this for specific solutions? I've only worked with this as an integer

Comment: @Willtswhite, see update.